# Complex iterations using multiple conditions (fee ditribution if certain conditions are met)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two large dataframes. million x 100K.

I have dataframe named `test_swaps`. This dataframe shows all trades, and fees accrued from each trade within `POOL_ADDRESS`.

```
    BLOCK_TIMESTAMP             LIQUIDITY       POOL_ADDRESS    PRICE_0_1   FEES
0   2021-12-02 03:42:56+00:00   7.770303e+21    0x360b9726186c0f62cc719450685ce70280774dc8  215.174737  163.787000
1   2021-12-02 04:02:18+00:00   7.770303e+21    0x360b9726186c0f62cc719450685ce70280774dc8  209.796784  223.138500
2   2021-12-02 04:03:52+00:00   7.770303e+21    0x360b9726186c0f62cc719450685ce70280774dc8  206.188879  199.961300
3   2021-12-02 06:55:37+00:00   8.165560e+19    0xfaa318479b7755b2dbfdd34dc306cb28b420ad12  203.100999  0.044125
4   2021-12-02 04:09:03+00:00   7.770303e+21    0x360b9726186c0f62cc719450685ce70280774dc8  204.329947  22.049300
...
```

and another dataframe `test_actions` which shows liquidity positions by NF_TOKEN_ID within `POOL_ADDRESS`. the data frame looks like this

```
    BLOCK_TIMESTAMP             NF_TOKEN_ID LIQUIDITY_cumsum    POOL_ADDRESS    PRICE_LOWER_0_1 PRICE_UPPER_0_1
0   2021-05-05 19:31:28+00:00   374.0   2.629662e+20    0xfaa318479b7755b2dbfdd34dc306cb28b420ad12  79.820552   81.189032
1   2021-05-05 21:12:56+00:00   374.0   0.000000e+00    0xfaa318479b7755b2dbfdd34dc306cb28b420ad12  79.820552   81.189032
2   2021-05-05 20:03:50+00:00   539.0   7.412937e+23    0x360b9726186c0f62cc719450685ce70280774dc8  0.012037    0.012781
3   2021-05-05 20:13:27+00:00   539.0   0.000000e+00    0x360b9726186c0f62cc719450685ce70280774dc8  0.012037    0.012781
4   2021-05-05 20:29:05+00:00   636.0   4.235670e+19    0x360b9726186c0f62cc719450685ce70280774dc8  66.672329   95.561691
```

My goal is to have a final output that looks like NF_TOKEN_ID, POOL_ADDRESS, FEES_ACCRUED, which shows how much each liquidity position has accrued fees.

A liquidity position `NF_TOKEN_ID` only accrues fees if certain conditions are met:

1. `POOL_ADDRESS` of the liquidity position and the trade should be the same
2. the position is within range (`test_actions['PRICE_LOWER_0_1']` <= `test_swaps['PRICE_0_1']` <=`test_actions['PRICE_UPPER_0_1']`,
3. the position is active at the time of trade. Currently `test_actions` is sorted such that the first date is when the position became active. The position may still be active or may be inactive depending on the last value of `LIQUIDITY_cumsum` (0 means all the liquidity is withdrawn, so inactive. For instance, `NF_TOKEN_ID` `374` above, the position was active between `2021-05-05 19:31:28+00:00` and  `2021-05-05 21:12:56+00:00`. `NF_TOKEN_ID` `636` has always been active bc liquidity was never fully withdrawn.

Fees from `test_swaps` need to be distributed to all liquidity positions that meet these conditions within each `POOL_ADDRESS`. Fee distribution is determined by the liquidity share for each position over the total liquidity within each pool: `test_actions['LIQUIDITY_cumsum']`/`test_swaps['LIQUIDITY']`.

I want my final output to look like NF_TOKEN_ID, POOL_ADDRESS, FEES_ACCRUED.

I have very large dataframes, so I am hoping to make the running time most efficient. let me know if something is unclear, and you need more explanation. I have been trying it but have not been successful, I would be very happy if humans can help me!

This is what i have done so far but it gives an error msg and takes a long time..:

```
# Convert timestamps to pandas datetime for efficient comparison
test_swaps['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(test_swaps['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'])
test_actions['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(test_actions['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'])

def get_active_positions(swap_time, nf_token_id, pool_address):
    # Filter for the specific NF_TOKEN_ID and POOL_ADDRESS
    positions = test_actions[(test_actions['NF_TOKEN_ID'] == nf_token_id) & 
                             (test_actions['POOL_ADDRESS'] == pool_address)]
    
    # Find the latest position start time that is before the swap time
    latest_start_time = positions[positions['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'] <= swap_time]['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'].max()
    
    # Check if there is any matching record
    if pd.isna(latest_start_time):
        return False

    # Check if the latest position is active
    latest_position = positions[positions['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'] == latest_start_time]
    if not latest_position.empty and latest_position['LIQUIDITY_cumsum'].iloc[-1] > 0:
        return True
    return False

# Initialize a dictionary to store fees accrued for each NF_TOKEN_ID and POOL_ADDRESS
fees_accrued = {}

# Iterate over the test_swaps dataframe
for index, swap in test_swaps.iterrows():
    # Check each position in test_actions
    for _, position in test_actions.iterrows():
        # Check if the swap price is within the range and if the position is active
        if (position['PRICE_LOWER_0_1'] <= swap['PRICE_0_1'] <= position['PRICE_UPPER_0_1'] and
                get_active_positions(swap['BLOCK_TIMESTAMP'], position['NF_TOKEN_ID'], position['POOL_ADDRESS'])):
            
            # Calculate liquidity share
            total_liquidity = test_swaps[test_swaps['POOL_ADDRESS'] == position['POOL_ADDRESS']]['LIQUIDITY'].sum()
            liquidity_share = position['LIQUIDITY_cumsum'] / total_liquidity
            
            # Accrue fees
            fees = liquidity_share * swap['FEES']
            key = (position['NF_TOKEN_ID'], position['POOL_ADDRESS'])
            fees_accrued[key] = fees_accrued.get(key, 0) + fees

# Convert the accrued fees dictionary to a DataFrame
result_df = pd.DataFrame(fees_accrued.items(), columns=['NF_TOKEN_ID_POOL_ADDRESS', 'FEES_ACCRUED'])
result_df[['NF_TOKEN_ID', 'POOL_ADDRESS']] = pd.DataFrame(result_df['NF_TOKEN_ID_POOL_ADDRESS'].tolist(), index=result_df.index)

# Final output
final_output = result_df[['NF_TOKEN_ID', 'POOL_ADDRESS', 'FEES_ACCRUED']]
```

Comment: I also hope that this isn't your actual table for storing financial data since it seems to be using floats EVERYWHERE ... which is bad, and causes lots of inaccuracies.

Comment: I have tried it myself as well. You know you don't have to be so condescending right? If you don't have something constructive to say, just go have a cup of tea pls.

Comment: In  my honest opinion the simplest and cleanest way to achieve what you want would be pandas' query method https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html You can chain a couple of queries and that should pretty much get you there at least most of the way. Can you try add some code here that generates some example data and makes a first attempt and then I can try and help you get it done.